# Integrating custom PHP script into drupal website

Tags: php, drupal, bigbluebutton

I'm trying to integrate a web conferencing tool, called Big Blue Button into my drupal website. I have downloaded a php script that will allow integration between my site and the Big Blue Button API.

In the readme, it says 'stick the entire directory into somewhere that can host php'. So the directory includes, for example, 'index.php', 'assets', 'css' and a few other files. So were do I put this and how can I access this Big Blue Button from a new page on my website? In my drupal folder, I have lots of different folders such as 'modules', 'profiles', 'sites' etc.

Can anyone help me to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to do it the Drupal way, i.e., create a custom module. If you're developing with Drupal, you may as well learn to do this.

You will find a lot of free Drupal tutorials here:
http://codekarate.com/daily-dose-of-drupal

Creating a single page is fairly easy. You will need to look at [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7). Download the [examples](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module and look at the Menu examples go create a simple page.

Create a subfolder in your custom module to hold the Big Blue Button files and try calling your php script from your menu callback function.

If you've never done this sort of thing, it may seem daunting at first, but have a try & you will find out it's not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try putting the entire folder on the same level as the Drupal folder, not within.

you need to create a page w/in Drupal and then link to the index.php of the tool.

That's the kind of thing I have done before, though not with this specific tool... in other words, I just used an iframe to pull it in. That or I've just opened it up in another window.

Integrating actually 'within' Drupal would take more and be creating a custom module which, judging from your question is probably more than you want or can do at this moment.

Try pulling it into an iframe... or possibly loading that index.php into a div via jquery using load().....there may be a newer method but have a look.